# Error: Must provide exactly one of these parameters customers:issuing card while using stripe

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments

I am trying to connect my app with firestore using stripe. It says "Error: Must provide exactly one of these parameters: [:customer, :issuing_card]" as you can see in the screen-gif below:-

[image]

My functions are deployed:-

[image]

My Webhooks are deployed as well:-

[image]

My viewcontroller is :-

```
  import UIKit
  import Stripe


 class CheckoutViewController: UIViewController {
 @IBOutlet weak var buyButton: UIButton!
 var paymentSheet: PaymentSheet?
     let backendCheckoutUrl = URL(string: "https://us-central1-newproject-    22cd1.cloudfunctions.net/handleWebhookEvents")! // Your backend endpoint

 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

buyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapCheckoutButton), for: .touchUpInside)
buyButton.isEnabled = false

// MARK: Fetch the PaymentIntent and Customer information from the backend
var request = URLRequest(url: backendCheckoutUrl)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
  guard let data = data,
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
   let customerId = json["customer"] as? String,
   let customerEphemeralKeySecret = json["ephemeralKey"] as? String,
   let paymentIntentClientSecret = json["paymentIntent"] as? String,
   let self = self else {
    // Handle error
    return
  }

  // MARK: Create a PaymentSheet instance
  var configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration()
  configuration.merchantDisplayName = "Example, Inc."
  configuration.customer = .init(id: customerId, ephemeralKeySecret:   customerEphemeralKeySecret)
  self.paymentSheet = PaymentSheet(paymentIntentClientSecret:      paymentIntentClientSecret, configuration: configuration)

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.buyButton.isEnabled = true
  }
    })
  .resume()
   }
   @objc
    func didTapCheckoutButton() {
  // MARK: Start the checkout process
  paymentSheet?.present(from: self) { paymentResult in
    // MARK: Handle the payment result
    switch paymentResult {
    case .completed:
      print("Your order is confirmed")
    case .canceled:
      print("Canceled!")
    case .failed(let error):
      print("Payment failed: \n\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
     }
      }
  }
```

Edit 1: Also, pasting index.js -

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');

 const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_123');
  
 // initialize admin SDK with defaults
 admin.initializeApp();


 /**
  * When a user is created, create a Stripe customer object for      them.  */

 exports.createStripeCustomer =   functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: user.email,
    metadata: { firebaseUID: user.uid },
    });
    await      admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({
   customer_id: customer.id,
     });
     return;
    });

 /**
  * Set up an ephemeral key.
  *
  * @see https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/basic#set-up- ephemeral-key
    * @see https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#ephemeral-   key*/

   exports.createEphemeralKey = functions.https.onCall(async         (data, context) => {
   // Checking that the user is authenticated.
   if (!context.auth) {
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error    details.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
     'failed-precondition',
     'The function must be called while authenticated!'
     );
      }
   const uid = context.auth.uid;
    try {
      if (!uid) throw new Error('Not authenticated!');
     // Get stripe customer id
     const customer = (
      await     admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(uid).get()
     ).data().customer_id;
     const key = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
        { customer },
       { apiVersion: data.api_version }
       );
      return key;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal',      error.message);
      }
      });

     /**
      * When a payment document is written on the client,
      * this function is triggered to create the PaymentIntent     in Stripe.
      *
      * @see https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android /basic#complete-the-payment */

     exports.createStripePayment = functions.firestore
    .document('stripe_customers/{userId}/payments/{pushId}')
   .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const { amount, currency } = snap.data();
     try {

   // Look up the Stripe customer id.
   const customer = (await  snap.ref.parent.parent.get()).data().customer_id;
    const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    { customer },
    { apiVersion: '2020-08-27' }
  );
  // Create a charge using the pushId as the idempotency key
  // to protect against double charges.
  const idempotencyKey = context.params.pushId;
  const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
    {
      amount,
      currency,
      customer,
    },
    { idempotencyKey }
  );
  payment.ephemeralKey = ephemeralKey.secret;
  // If the result is successful, write it back to the database.
  await snap.ref.set(payment);
} catch (error) {
  // We want to capture errors and render them in a user-friendly way, while
  // still logging an exception with StackDriver
  console.log(error);
  await snap.ref.set({ error: userFacingMessage(error) }, { merge: true });
       await reportError(error, { user: context.params.userId      });
      }
     });

  /**
   * Helper function to update a payment record in Cloud    Firestore. */
    const updatePaymentRecord = async (id) => {
    // Retrieve the payment object to make sure we have an up to           date status.
     const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(id);
     const customerId = payment.customer;
     // Get customer's doc in Firestore.
     const customersSnap = await admin
     .firestore()
     .collection('stripe_customers')
     .where('customer_id', '==', customerId)
      .get();
     if (customersSnap.size !== 1) throw new Error('User not found!');
     // Update record in Firestore
     const paymentsSnap = await customersSnap.docs[0].ref
     .collection('payments')
     .where('id', '==', payment.id)
     .get();
      if (paymentsSnap.size !== 1) throw new Error('Payment not   found!');
     await paymentsSnap.docs[0].ref.set(payment);
   };

    /**
    * A webhook handler function for the relevant Stripe events.
    * @see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/handling-payment-      events?lang=node#build-your-own-webhook */
    exports.handleWebhookEvents =     functions.https.onRequest(async (req, resp) => {
      const relevantEvents = new Set([
      'payment_intent.succeeded',
      'payment_intent.processing',
      'payment_intent.payment_failed',
     'payment_intent.canceled',
       ]);

      let event;

     // Instead of getting the `Stripe.Event`
      // object directly from `req.body`,
       // use the Stripe webhooks API to make sure
     // this webhook call came from a trusted source
      try {
       event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        req.rawBody,
       req.headers['stripe-signature'],
       functions.config().stripe.webhooksecret
         );
        } catch (error) {
        console.error('❗️ Webhook Error: Invalid Secret');
        resp.status(401).send('Webhook Error: Invalid Secret');
       return;
          }

         if (relevantEvents.has(event.type)) {
         try {
         switch (event.type) {
         case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
         case 'payment_intent.processing':
         case 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
         case 'payment_intent.canceled':
         const id = event.data.object.id;
         await updatePaymentRecord(id);
         break;
         default:
         throw new Error('Unhandled relevant event!');
          }
          } catch (error) {
        console.error(
       `❗️ Webhook error for [${event.data.object.id}]`,
       error.message
          );
        resp.status(400).send('Webhook handler failed. View    Function logs.');
      return;
     }
      }

    // Return a response to Stripe to acknowledge receipt of the   event.
     resp.json({ received: true });
      });

    /* When a user deletes their account, clean up after them */
      exports.cleanupUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async  (user) => {
       const dbRef =          admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers');
      const customer = (await dbRef.doc(user.uid).get()).data();
      await stripe.customers.del(customer.customer_id);
     // Delete the customers payments & payment methods in  firestore.
      const snapshot = await dbRef
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('payment_methods')
     .get();
      snapshot.forEach((snap) => snap.ref.delete());
      await dbRef.doc(user.uid).delete();
      return;
      });

    /**
       * To keep on top of errors, we should raise a verbose   error report with Stackdriver rather
      * than simply relying on console.error. This will    calculate users affected + send you email
      * alerts, if you've opted into receiving them. */

       // [START reporterror]

        function reportError(err, context = {}) {
        // This is the name of the StackDriver log stream that   will receive the log
       // entry. This name can be any valid log stream name, but must contain "err"
      // in order for the error to be picked up by StackDriver Error Reporting.
        const logName = 'errors';
        const log = logging.log(logName);

         // https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api /ref_v2beta1/rest/v2beta1/MonitoredResource
         const metadata = {
         resource: {
         type: 'cloud_function',
         labels: { function_name: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME },
          },
           };

        // https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference   /rest/v1beta1/ErrorEvent
       const errorEvent = {
       message: err.stack,
        serviceContext: {
        service: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME,
       resourceType: 'cloud_function',
         },
        context: context,
         };

     // Write the error log entry
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     log.write(log.entry(metadata, errorEvent), (error) => {
      if (error) {
    return reject(error);
       }
    return resolve();
    });
     });
     }

  // [END reporterror]

                /* Sanitize the error message for the user.*/
               function userFacingMessage(error) {
     return error.type
       ? error.message
       : 'An error occurred, developers have been alerted';
       }
```

How to sort-it-out ? Thanks.

Comment: Which line is producing this error? You've shared a giant block of code that does dozens of operations on your datastore and the Stripe API. Which call is failing? You need to do some initial debugging to narrow the scope of the problem. Additionally, the error mentions Issuing, are you using the Issuing API anywhere?

Comment: You also leaked your test mode secret key, so you should roll that: https://stripe.com/docs/keys#rolling-keys